# python py2exe can't find pywinusb

Tags: python

I am using `Python 2.7.8`.

I installed the following: 
  `py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe` and `pywinusb-0.3.3`

I have a script that I am trying to run.  When I do I get the following error:

```
C:\Python27\MyScripts\VMS\Python_Firmware_Upgrader-4_00_02\Python_Firmware_Upgrader\python-msp430-tools\win32>python ./setup-combined-tools
py2exe.py
changed directory to C:\Python27\MyScripts\VMS\Python_Firmware_Upgrader-4_00_02\Python_Firmware_Upgrader\python-msp430-tools
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup-combined-tools-py2exe.py", line 47, in <module>
    zipfile = "lib/shared.zip",
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1297, in find_needed_modules
    mf.import_hook(mod)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_package
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named pywinusb
```

I added pywinusb under the options\packages as suggested with the same results.  Any other suggestions:

```
setup(
    name = 'http://mspgcc.sourceforge.net',
    author="Chris Liechti",
    author_email="cliechti@gmx.net",
    url="http://launchpad.net/python-msp430-tools/",

    version = '0.6',
    options = { "py2exe":
        {
            'dist_dir': 'bin',
            'excludes': ['javax.comm', 'macpath', 'TERMIOS', 'FCNTL',
                    'os2emxpath', '_parjtag',
                    'IronPythonConsole', 'System', 'System.IO.Ports',      'System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard', 'clr',
                'modes.editingmodes', 'startup', 'Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'wx'],
            'packages': ['msp430', 'msp430.asm', 'msp430.memory', 'msp430.shell',
                    'msp430.gdb', 'msp430.jtag', 'msp430.bsl', 'msp430.bsl5', **'pywinusb'**],
            'includes': ['pywinusb', 'EasyDialogs'],
            'dll_excludes': ['HIL.dll', 'MSP430.dll', 'MSP430mspgcc.dll'],
            'optimize': 2,
        }
    },
    console = [
       "scripts/msp430-bsl.py",
        "scripts/msp430-jtag.py",
        "scripts/msp430-tool.py",
    ],
    windows = [
        {
            'script': "scripts/msp430-downloader.py",
            'icon_resources': [(0x0001, 'win32/downloader.ico')]
        },
    ],
    zipfile = "lib/shared.zip", 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

These type of errors when trying to py2exe an application can most of the time be fixed by adding the package, in this case'pywinusb', to the 'packages' option of py2exe to force to include that package.

Comment: thanks for the response.  i am a newbie, how would I do this?

Comment: I added pywinusb under packages and I still get the same error.  Any other ideas?    options = { "py2exe":
        {
            'packages': ['msp430', 'msp430.asm',  'msp430.memory', 'msp430.shell',
                        'msp430.gdb', 'msp430.jtag', 'msp430.bsl', 'msp430.bsl5', 'pywinusb'],
            'includes': ['pywinusb', 'EasyDialogs'],
            'dll_excludes': ['HIL.dll', 'MSP430.dll', 'MSP430mspgcc.dll'],
            'optimize': 2,
        }

Comment: @brent, can you remove 'pywinusb' from the 'includes' option.  Just to make sure the "**" around 'pywinusb' in the packages option are just shown here and are not in your actual setup.py?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following link:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs

Basically it says => py2exe does not currently (as of 0.6.5) work out of the box if some of your program's dependencies are in .egg form

When I ran the pywinusb setup.u as follows

python setup.py install_lib

I got the uncompressed folder => C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywinusb

Comment: yes eggs have to installed uncompressed to use them with py2exe, except with the latest version of it, but that only works for Py3.x.